# I am getting the "document is not defined" error when using webpack to bundle some package for node

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am using `webpack5` to bundle some packages together as an online lib and using `eval` in Nodejs to execute the code after fetching it.

But it seems that all the packages assume they are running in the browser environment not in Nodejs because of so many `document is not defined` errors. I had set the `externalsPresets.node: true` and `output.libraryTarget: "commonjs"`. It's ok if I `require` them directly in Nodejs.

Comment: `document is not defined` - It is correct. Document API is not a part of Node.js, it runs on browser. You can't use it on Server Side.

Comment: But in fact all of them support for nodejs, such as `puppeteer-core` and `axios`.

Comment: Yes, these are third party libs which are being support by node.js, but document is on browser, you don't have access to it. It will only run in browser. Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use webpack to bundle them together, but I need to use them in local electon client. So I use http request to get the files and use `eval` to run it. This is because of some known issues of `bytenode` so I have to bundle them seperately from the main process code

Comment: I have created a code repo: https://github.com/Cinux-Chosan/code-sample

Comment: Would you  please help me to solve the problem in `reademe.md`

Comment: I found that in the source code in `node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js`, the function `getDefaultAdapter`  requires different modules according to different conditions, but in `dist/main.js`, the `getDefaultAdapter` requires the same module. But I don't know why.

Comment: This problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

just set webpack.config.js

```js
{
    ...
    target: 'your target env'
    ...
}
```

I thought webpack5 does not support the target attribute, which was obviously my mistake

see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/